# AngularJS Accessing Value In Querystring

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Im trying to accessing a value in a querystring.

Here's what i see in the browser:

```
http://localhost:1010/products/chairs.html?searchMe=testing123
```

And in my Controller, i have:

```
var mySearchMeQuery = $location.search().searchMe;

console.log("searchMe = " + mySearchMeQuery );
```

In my console.log, i am seeing: `searchMe  = undefined`

I have checked i have $location injected in my controller.

** Solution must work in IE8+ **

Answer (score 1):

$location works only if you use path with hash (#). See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$location.search()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

It returns an object key-value pairs; The key is your query string and the value is the query string value.

Example:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.queryString = $location.search();
    // returns {searchMe: "testing123"}
}
```

And if you want to print the same message as in your question

```
 console.log("searchMe = " + $location.search().searchMe);
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the need for $window?

Comment: Yes, it will work. It works with query string, and doesn't depend on hashes.

Comment: `$window` is not needed.

Comment: See JanBarta's respsonse, $location only works with #

Comment: :) I'm sure it doesn't. Just try the code sample and see if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject dependecy $routeParams and get the parameter value using something like this:

```
$routeParams.searchMe
```

[Docs on routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams)

UPDATED Answer:

I have updated an existing fiddle which had $routeParams as an example. If you click on Moby link and check console over there you can see that SearchMe as a querystring is available.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3NHF/61/)

Comment: tried, var text = $routeParams.searchMe; console.log(text); the output was 'undefined'... Injected $routeParams into my controller.